# How can I track down cause of recent change in memory of server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use a SQL Server database on an almost daily basis. Only a few of us have direct access to this server. As recently as a week ago, it had over 20 GB of free space. Yesterday this was down to 10 MB. I'm trying to track down the cause of this sudden drop in available memory.

[image: Memory comparison]

I have tried running some of the provided reports in SSMS. I can see which tables are the most expensive, but there aren't really any surprises here. Losing 20 GB in a week doesn't make sense to me and so I'd like to see which queries/tables caused this change.

Comment: Unless you have turned tracing on, you probably won't have very good information. Are you aware of roughly how large you expect the MDF and LDF files to be? Did a query affect a lot of rows and grow your log file really large? Is the growth size/percent on the data or log file really large? How much free space is in your data/log file? The OS event viewer should record an event when the space dropped that low, so you can pinpoint *when*, but you need tracing to determine *how*, which isn't on by default.

Comment: And also, unfortunately, this question isn't really [on-topic](/help/on-topic) for [so], so your question may end up getting closed.

Comment: My guess is you had a lot of data movement and tempdb is bloated. But honestly running a sql server with such a tiny hard drive is going to be challenging forever.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're right. I have 29 GB reserved but only 5 MB used. Any ideas on how to truncate, find some space here?

Comment: Well...if tempdb grew as the result of a regular process it will just do it again. I would strongly suggest getting a MUCH larger hard drive. The normal you referred to would horrify me. 20GB of free space is nearly out of space and your entire hard drive of free space is getting low.

Comment: Agreed. I restarted the server and that released memory back. Now sitting at what feels like a comfortable ~60GB of free space :/